# Why ETH gas fee is still expensive >$5 - $10 after sharding + POS?

Tags: gas, proof-of-stake, fees, sharding, pow

I just notice that ETH charges $40 for a tx at the time POW + high demand
$5-$10 at the time POW + avg low demand
And $5-$10 at the time POS + low demand (current 2023)
So can you explain more why the fee is still so high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to Proof of Stake [reduced the costs for creating the blocks in the blockchain (by around 99.95%)](https://ethereum.org/en/roadmap/merge/#merge-and-energy), but itself was not designed for reducing the costs of transacting/writing to the blockchain.  POS reduced energy costs, not gas/transaction fees.

From https://ethereum.org/en/roadmap/merge/#accordion-button-:R17b7elaeiau:

> Gas fees are a product of network demand relative to the capacity of
> the network. The Merge deprecated the use of proof-of-work,
> transitioning to proof-of-stake for consensus, but did not
> significantly change any parameters that directly influence network
> capacity or throughput.
>
> With a [rollup-centric roadmap](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/a-rollup-centric-ethereum-roadmap/4698), efforts are being
> focused on scaling user activity at layer 2, while enabling layer 1
> Mainnet as a secure decentralized settlement layer optimized for
> rollup data storage to help make rollup transactions exponentially
> cheaper. The transition to proof-of-stake is a critical precursor to
> realizing this.

Answer (score 4):

Currently sharding is not implemented in Ethereum and there isn't a complete plan to implement sharding yet.

- None of the current production nodes have any sharding support
- There is no clear technical plan how to implement sharding

Blockchains that support state sharding include

- [NEAR](https://near.org/papers/nightshade/)
- [MultiversX previously known as Elrond](https://docs.multiversx.com/technology/adaptive-state-sharding/)

These blochains have lower fees than Ethereum, so sharding is working correctly, although the usage rates are not 1:1 comparable.

Comment: I clearly remember that before the merge, the gas price could drop as low as 1 or 2 GWEI when the network was not busy, but since the merge, I haven't seen any situation where the gas price falls below 10 GWEI or so. Does it have any logical reason?

Comment: It is a function of supply (does not change) and demand (changes)